# Как реализовать батут в 3d infinity runner

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть игрок, который бежит вперёд + им можно управлять вправо/влево. В моей игре есть препятствия и встречаются такие типы препятствий, которые нельзя объезжать (только перепрыгнуть), но вот незадача - игрок не может самостоятельно вызывать прыжок, вместо этого есть игровой объект батут, расположенный перед, непроходимым по земле, препятствием.

Вопрос такой:

> Как красиво реализовать запрыгивание на батут, а затем перепрыгивание
> через препятствия?

Я сделал анимацию запрыгивания на батут, анимацию полёта после отталкивания, анимацию батуту, но не знаю как это всё связать вместе + что делать, если игрок в самый последний момент решил зайти на полосу с батутом?

Вот пример того, как это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как по вашему игрок может запрыгнуть на батут, если он не может прыгать?

Comment: Модераторы, зачем вы по пять раз изменяете правку ответа? Я удалил твердый знак в слове ОБЪЕЗЖАТЬ, чтоб получилось обедать, от слово бежать, я поставил запятую в сложном предложении (по правилам русского языка в сложных предложениях всегда ставится запятая, вне зависимости от наличия союза и). Потом Александр Чернир удаляет мою правку, пишет неправильно, и это ПРИНИМАЕТСЯ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ставим на батут триггер, а потом rigidbody.AddForce (риджидбоди находим через GetComponent)